# How to create a search with or clause using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create a query with Elasticsearch Java API but I don't know how to create an OR clause? What I want to query is;

```
SELECT * 
FROM USERS 
WHERE (user.name = "admin") AND (user.message LIKE "test*") AND (user.age = "30" OR user.status = "major")
```

I have created a query like below but I don't know how to create an OR clause like sql query;

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "admin"));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("message", "test*"));

boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("age", "30"));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status","major"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need to capture the OR condition inside another `bool/should` query

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "admin"));
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("message", "test*"));

BoolQueryBuilder orQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
orQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("age", "30"));
orQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status","major"));
orQuery.minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
boolQueryBuilder.must(orQuery);
```

PS: not sure why you have a `mustNot` for your second constraint.

Comment: Sorry my mistake its not "mustNot". By the way is my "like" query is correct? (I mean QueryBuilders.matchQuery("message", "test*"))

Comment: You cannot have wildcards in `match` queries, but you can use a `queryStringQuery` or a `wildcardQuery` instead

Answer (score 0):

The "should" keyword in **bool** queries works like "OR", but in Elasticsearch those queries are not very sharp as everything is scored.
Have a look at:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html#bool-query

Also there are very good examples in the book *Elasticsearch in Action*.